# Placing multiple images centered and fixed spacing with Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I want to place multiple (varies from 0 to 8) images centered and fixed spacing (as the screenshots following), but I have no idea how to do.

when 8 images are in the layout(what I want to do)

[image]

when 2 images are in the layout(what I want to do)

[image]

---

This is what I see with this code when 2 images are in the layout

[image]

```
BoxLayout:
    Image:
        source: "yellow.png"
    Image:
        source: "red.png"
    Image:
        source: "yellow.png
    Image:
        ...
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to put the **BoxLayout** inside of another **Layout**.
For example:

```
FloatLayout:
    BoxLayout:
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}
        spacing: 10 # some space between images
        # you may want to play with size or size_hint here 
        Image:
            source: "yellow.png"
        Image:
            source: "red.png"
        Image:
            source: "yellow.png
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked well with size_hint_x: len(self.children) * 5 in BoxLayout.

Comment: NP, you can accept the answer if you think its helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have just to set the spacing in your BoxLayout:

ex:

```
BoxLayout:
    spacing: 10 # by example
    Image:
        source: "yellow.png"
    Image:
        source: "red.png"
    Image:
        source: "yellow.png
    Image:
        ...
```